# Why is CUDA not found?

Tags: macos, shell, cuda

I'm trying to setup CUDA on a Macbook Pro, I've installed cuda with brew:

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
brew cask install cuda
```

Added this to my .bash_profile

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

I also installed cuDNN v5.1

```
sudo mv include/cudnn.h /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/include/
sudo mv lib/libcudnn* /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib
sudo ln -s /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/libcudnn* /usr/local/cuda/lib/
```

I'm now trying to test it:

```
cp -r /usr/local/cuda/samples ~/cuda-samples
pushd ~/cuda-samples
make
```

but I get this error:

```
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
clang++  -rpath /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib -L/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib -framework CUDA -o clock_nvrtc clock.o  -lnvrtc
ld: framework not found CUDA
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [clock_nvrtc] Error 1
make: *** [0_Simple/clock_nvrtc/Makefile.ph_build] Error 2
```

Comment: It looks like that homebrew tap only installs the CUDA toolkit, but not the CUDA driver. Since homebrew just downloads the normal NVidia installer and runs it, the simplest fix is probably to just run the graphical installer again and select the driver for installation as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out, I didn't have nvida graphics card :(

Comment: just a friendly reminder about accepting your amswer

Comment: @talonmies you're the real mvp!